# Scala headOption not found

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I migrated my Play version from 2.3 to 2.4. In my previous version I used `firstOption` to get the latest record from DB. But that functionality is removed in latest version of slick. I searched and found that we can use `headOption` instead of `firstOption`. The following is my code :

```
def findById(id: String)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Option[Client]] = 
  Future {
    DB.withConnection { implicit session =>
      Clients.filter(c => c.id === id).firstOption
    }
  }
```

The imports I have used are as follows :

```
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.db.DB
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
```

When I tried to replace `firstOption` with `headOption` it shows error 'cannot resolve symbol headOption'. Am I missing any import statements? Is there any alternative way to fix this?

Comment: private val Clients = TableQuery[Client]                                                              And then use this, db.run(Clients.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption).

Comment: It shows return type error

Comment: Can you please post your new code snippet? As same line of code is working fine for me.

Comment: When I assign the result to a val and return it shows no error.. Thanks for the help

Comment: It is not actually required, as we know that in Scala last statement always considered as return statement. Strange but good to know that finally it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try
Clients.filter(c => c.id === id).result.headOption

Your object structure is not clear to me but the way I use it is:

```
val query = tableInstance.filter(_.id === id)
val action = query.result.headOption
db.run(action)
```

where tableInstance is of slick's TableQuery type

Answer (score 0):

Try to import

`scala.collections.convert.WrapAsScala._`

This solved the problem on my side.